# Matrix form of trivector triple product

Tags: exterior-algebra

If $a \wedge b = a \otimes b - b \otimes a$ then what is $a \wedge b \wedge c$

I know it's supposed to be a trivector but what is it in Matrix form?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't $a\wedge b=b\otimes a - a\otimes b=\begin{bmatrix}0&a_yb_x-a_xb_y\\a_xb_y-a_yb_x&0\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 1):

$e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3$ = $
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$
a \wedge b \wedge c = a \otimes b \otimes c - a \otimes c \otimes b + c \otimes a \otimes b -
c \otimes b \otimes a +
b \otimes c \otimes a - b \otimes a \otimes c$